# Distinguishing the dev server from production efficiently for PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'd like to be able to distinguish my dev servers from production (and beta testing) servers automatically in the most efficient way, and without relying on something like the HTTP_HOST. I would this to be transparent to the other developers, so they don't have to worry about it.

I'm using pre-compiling css and compressing js when I deploy to production, but I want the uncompressed js (and on-the-fly complied css) on production. A simple "development" flag would be enough to distinguish them, but **what is the best way to get this variable into the development environment** without wasting resources in production?

My current plan is to dynamically rewrite a php (or ini file, to be parsed with parse_ini_file) file as part of our deploy process, setting developer to false (I may rewrite this file anyway to set the new filenames for the compiled css and js). However, I'm worried that if something unexpected were to go wrong with the deploy script, as written, there might be some risk that the developer mode would be pushed to production. In other words, I want there to be something specific about the development environments such that there is no risk that a production system would be mistaken for a development system.

I considered using separate user.ini files to set custom "development" flags to distinguish this, but I had trouble getting that to work, and wanted to see if there was a better solution before I spent any more time on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is set the flag in our httpd.conf file on each server. So for your Dev box, you can just add this to your apache conf `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development`. For your production box, do the same `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production`.

In your php application config, you can do something like this:

```
switch ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']){

    case 'production':

        define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'SOME VALUE');

        break;

    case 'development':

        define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'SOME VALUE');

        break;
}
```

Comment: This is a very reliable solution that I have used before, however I would suggest that you be careful to default the detection to non-prod. This way if you forget to set the environment variable on a new server it behaves like a non-prod box. Also you can restrict the variable to specific virtual hosts by using: `<VirtualHost *:80>  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production  ...` in the specific apache site config.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put all the dev servers onto one subdomain and use that via HTTP_HOST, but if you want to avoid that, I'd say the best way would be to use a flag in the config file on those servers (what went wrong if this is what you tried?) or test for a particular file/directory whatever being present, which will be missing on production. The flag in the config file is the method I use and the one I see the most. Pretty hard to set it accidentally.

Alternatively, you could just have a flag set via GET, which switches to the dev versions of the libraries when you need them.

I'm a little unclear about what hasn't worked so far - is it actually the continuous integration stuff causing the problem here?

Comment: To clarify, on our dev server, we have apache running a set of virtual hosts, one (or more) for each developer. Inside the <directory> section of my virtual host, I added:  
      AllowOverride All
      php_value user_ini.filename "/var/www/foo/dev.ini"

Comment: However, after restarting apache when I look at the value for user_ini.filename in my php code, (using ini_get) I get the default value. This is my first time messing with an apache conf file, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: That's pretty normal when messing with Apache conf files ;) AllowOverride is about .htaccess files isn't it? I'm a bit rusty, but I think you'll still need to add that as a config override in the file system for each user.

Answer (score 0):

At our company we are distinguishing our several dev servers from production by the means of the config file which is excluded from the commit and contain the actual settings for the each environment, as well as the variable which indicates the server state.